# Convert year, day of year and fractional hour to a real date in python

Tags: python

I would like to convert arrays of year, day of year and fractional hours to a real date.
Thats my code up to now:

`` year = [2012,2012,2012]
day = [2,3,4] #day of year
hour = [12,12,12]
import datetime
import pytz
dt=list()
for i in range(len(year)):
   dt.append(datetime.datetime(year[i], day[i], hour[i],tzinfo=pytz.UTC))
dt=np.array(dt)
print dt ` ``

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: Hello, Sabrina, welcome to Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow, unlike some online forums you may have used, is not a help center (although we do like to be helpful). It is not a discussion forum. It is a **question**-and-**answer** site. Readers, such as yourself, ask questions and other readers answer them. Your post contains no question, however. So I have to ask you -- **What is your question?**

Comment: Use `zip()` to convert `[2012,2012,2012], [2,3,4], [12,12,12]` into a list of 'real' dates: `(2012, 2, 12), (2012, 3, 12), (2012, 4, 12)`... but is that what you're actually trying to do? Be more specific with your question.

Comment: I think the question here is somewhat obvious: It's "How do I convert year, day of year, …?" It would be more helpful if she explained what went wrong, but if you just run her code it will tell you.

Comment: Hello Rob, sorry for being not specific enough. I used Stack Overflow for the first time and had some trouble with formatting my post correctly. In the end I just forgot to add my final question.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor for [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) objects takes a year, month, and day, and optional hour, minute, etc. So, you're passing the day as the month, the hour as the day, and nothing as the hour.

On top of that, `day` has to be a day of the month, not a day of the year, and `hour` has to be an integer (with separate minutes, seconds, and microseconds if appropriate).

One easy way around this is to create a `datetime` with the start of the year, and add the days and hours on with `timedelta`.

While we're at it, you can make the code a bit cleaner by iterating directly over the arrays instead of over `range(len(…))`.

```
for y, d, h in zip(year, day, hour):
    d0 = datetime.datetime(y, 1, 1, tzdata=pytz.UTC)
    dt.append(d0 + datetime.timedelta(days=d, hours=h))
```

---

As a side note, I'd name the list variables `years`, `days`, `hours`, and `dts`, so I could name the individual iteration values `year`, `day`, `hour`, and `dt`. And, while we're at it, I'd write this as a helper function and a list comprehension rather than a `for` loop and a complicated body. And put the imports at the time. Like this:

```
import datetime
import pytz

years = [2012,2012,2012]
days = [2,3,4] #day of year
hours = [12,12,12]

def make_date(year, day, hour, tzdata=pytz.UTC):
    dt = datetime.datetime(year, 1, 1, tzdata=tzdata)
    return dt + datetime.timedelta(days=day, hours=hour)

dts = [make_date(year, day, hour) for year, day, hour in zip(years, days, hours)]
```

---

The above works for your original question, where `years` and `days` are lists of integers and `hours` is a list of floats (as in your description) or integers (as in your sample code). It will also work if `days` is a list of floats, but not `years`.

However, from a comment, it sounds like these are actually numpy arrays of `int64` values. Although you call them floats, `int64` is not a floating-point type, it's an integer type. And you can convert an `int64` to a plain Python `int` with no loss of range or precision.

So, because the `datetime` and `timedelta` constructors won't accept `int64` values, just convert each one into an `int`:

```
def make_date(year, day, hour, tzdata=pytz.UTC):
    dt = datetime.datetime(int(year), 1, 1, tzdata=tzdata)
    return dt + datetime.timedelta(days=int(day), hours=int(hour))
```

If your hours were actually of a floating-point type as you originally claimed, like `float64`, you'd want to use `float(hour)` instead of `int(hour)`.

---

One last thing: From your description, I guessed that your days were 0-based (and your hours, but that's not likely to be wrong). If your days are actually 1-based, you're obviously going to need to do `days=int(day)-1`.

Comment: Hi Rob, thank you very much for your helpful comments. I do understand the constructor for datetime much better now. Thanks also for hints how to make the code shorter/better. For the given example it does work now.

Comment: @SabrinaNiebling: You're welcome, Tabitha. :) (I'm not Rob, but it's easy to miss who you're talking to on this site. Plus, being mistaken for someone as helpful as him isn't an insult. So, no harm done.)

Comment: sorry for mixing up the names. I am still a bit confused by the way Stack Overflow works...

Comment: Hi Abarnert, as mentioned above the code does work now for the given example. Unfortunately the reality is a bit more complex,

Comment: More complex in what way? Do you have an example it doesn't work for?

Comment: Hi Abarnert, as mentioned above the code does work now for the given example. Unfortunately the reality is a bit more complex. `years` and `days` are floats, not integers (e. g. 2012. instead 2012) and `hours` are fractional hours (e. g. 12.7384) How do I handle this? When I try to run the code with the real data, I get an type error saying 'unsupported type for timedelta days component numpy.int64' I am able to convert the data type for years from float to integer by using `years = years.astype(int)`. This does not work for `days` unfortunately.

Comment: @SabrinaNiebling: Your original example uses plain Python lists and numbers, but now you're showing numpy values. It would have been clearer if you'd mentioned that from the start. Also, `int64` is not a float type, it's an integer type, which makes a very big difference. Anyway, let me edit the answer, because it's hard to give enough details in a comment.

Comment: Hi Abarnert, thanks for all your help and sorry for being so confusing when asking questions. You were right with all your assumptions concerning my original data. With your code I get exactly what I would like to have.